# Are there some permalink typology better than others for SEO?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, url, seo

I am pretty new in WordPress and on my blog I am using permalinks.

I have seen that there are 5 topologies of permalinks and I don't know if some types are better than others for search engines for indexation.

At the moment I am using this typology:

```
example.com/2013/04/22/articolo d'esempio/
```

that is composed by: the base URL of my blog, the complete date of the post and the post name.

So I have the URL of posts like this:

```
example.com/2013/04/18/2-hello-world-in-spring-mvc/
```

Is this a good URL or are there some other permalink typologies that are better for search engine indexing (or for some other reasons)?

Comment: You say there are "5 topologies"... so what are the other 4?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the URLs are *static* there are only minor differences.

URL become part of the SERP and like with your page's title not
all characters are shown. So I decided against having the date as
part of my URL to make the URL shorter. This makes them also better
readable when written somewhere else.

Also I replace all special characters with the minus (-) sign.

Last but not least I preferred having the file-type `.htm` as part of
the URL because this makes clear that it refers to a page and not a
directory.

So my URL look like this: `/articolo-d-esempio.htm`

If you worry your URL might not be unique (I didn't) without the date 
then you could put the date after the post title like this: `/articolo-d-esempio-22042013.htm`

(day and month might be sufficient...)

Answer (score 0):

The URL isn't important for SEO. And it's really logic, because otherwise everyone would spam it.

Just look at the most popular newspapers, which only use numbers in their URL, in order to keep it shorter.